# how to redirect anchor tag link without reloading the HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, href

I want my anchor tag to redirect on given path, but without reloading the whole web page. My anchor tag looks like below:

```
<a href="/test" (click)="goHome()">Click me</a>
```

below is my component in which I am assigning a HTML tag to a variable Htmlsnipet as a string:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-form',
templateUrl: './form.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

htmlSnippet = `<a href="/test">Click me</a>`;
@ViewChild('element') public viewElement: ElementRef;
public element: any;
flag = true
```

}

and below is the template in which I want that HTML to be rendered as innerHTML

```
<div>
<span #element [innerHTML] = "htmlSnippet | safe: 'html'"></span>
</div>
```

all the things are working but when I am clicking on "click me" it is reloading the application.

Comment: There is no link on "Click me"

Comment: Please, be more descriptive to solve an issue.

Comment: @Progressive added that code

Comment: Are you working on Angular?

Comment: If you want to redirect on goHome() function click then use href = "javascript:void(0)"

Comment: @7urkm3n I want to navigate to a new HTML page from a angular 4 component. I can do it with href but it is reloading the whole angular application which I dnt want.

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT yes, with angular 4

Comment: If it is from component, then you can use `Router` and in the function you can do `this.router.navigate(['/page-to-redirect]);`

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan I have tried that but when I am navigating from function through window.location.href("/test"), it is again reloading the application

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT this is in innerHTML, and I think its function won't be accessible in component

Comment: @NileemaGaykwad no, it will be accesable, did you try it. In your constructor, you should do `dependency injection` for the `Router`

Comment: @NileemaGaykwad, if you update your question with component code and html code(innerHTML thing), then we can understand what you are trying to do!!!

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT edited the question, please look into that

Comment: Is there any reason why `htmlSnippet` needs to be a string rendered via innerHTML? Are you able to just get the `href` value so that you could pass it to `router.navigate`?

Comment: @Ash I can get the href value only when it is redirected so after that can not do router.navigate

Comment: I think the confusion here is that you want to use the Angular Router but aren't implementing it in a way that Angular will recognise. See what happens with a simple string replace to use routerLink instead (assuming you can't directly change the string value), e.g. `this.htmlSnippet = this.htmlSnippet.replace('href', 'routerLink');`. Otherwise have a read through of https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

Comment: @Ash string in HtmlSnippet is a plain HTML tag so it won't allow routerLink

Comment: `htmlSnippet` in your example is an anchor. You can use `routerLink` on any clickable element. Have a look at the router guide https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: thank you all, this has been solved by prevent-default and custom events.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using `Angular`. You can use router and navigate to wherever you want.

Add following code in your component. Make sure you have defined route for home (e.g. `home`)

```
// import Router
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

// add in constructor
constructor(private router: Router) {

}

// modify your method goHome as:
goHome() {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but this is not the case. goHome function is in innerHTML with angular.

Comment: @NileemaGaykwad, if you use window.location.href("/test") you are saying that reload the page. You can try using hastlocation strategies https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using `href="/test"`, so the browser will recognise it and triggers page load behaviour try to get content from the target path remotely, which is not what you expected obviously.

Instead, you should remove `href="/test"` and use `routerLink="/test"`, this attribute serves the correct Angular routes.

One more thing, I see you defined a `(click)="goHome()"` for this link tag as well, this is confusing and conflict with what you did for trying to specify the route path for this link.

Even though you can have both as you wish but I would suggest keeping either `(click)="goHome()"` or `routerLink="/test"`.

If you want to do something extra, use `goHome()` method and navigate to home screen manually as what Anshuman suggested. Otherwise simply define the route and use `routerLink="/test"`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a directive on the element you are calling [innerHtml]

```
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private router: Router, private renderer: Renderer2) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // wait for DOM rendering
      this.reinsertScripts();
      this.reinsertLinks();
    });
  }
  reinsertLinks(): void {
    const links = <HTMLAnchorElement[]>this.elementRef.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('a');

    if (links) {
      const linksInitialLength = links.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < linksInitialLength; i++) {
        const link = links[i];

        if (link.host === window.location.host) {
          this.renderer.listen(link, 'click', event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.router.navigate([
              link.href
                .replace(link.host, '')
                .replace(link.protocol, '')
                .replace('//', '')
            ]);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
```